# Problemas al recuperar registros del fetch()

Tags: php

Esta clase obtiene los registros de la tabla.
El ***select*** solo tiene algunos campos de la tabla.
Tengo algunas preguntas:
1) Por qué **$registros** solamente guarda el último registro si está dentro del while? 
2) El resultado de la consulta está dentro de **$row**, es necesario identificar los campos con los setters (vista)? O eso lo puedo hacer fuera de la clase?

```
public function listarDatos() {
    try {
            $sql = "SELECT campo1, campo2, campo3 FROM tabla WHERE campo4 = condicion";
            $bd = new Conn();
            $stmt = $bd->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) { 
                $registros = new registrosVista();
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                    $registros->setCampo1( $row['campo1'] );
                    $registros->setCampo2( $row['campo2'] );
                    $registros->setCampo3( $row['campo3'] );
                }
            } else { 
                $registros = NULL;
            }
            return $registros;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die ('No se puede ejecutar la consulta');
        }
}
```

Comment: Dos cosas: si `condicion` no es un dato externo, puedes usar `query` en vez de `prepare/execute`. Ya @alanfcm indicó en su respuesta por qué tu código no funciona como esperas. Pero viendo que estás usando una `clase`... otra cosa que puedes hacer es mapear el resultado a esa clase mediante `$stm->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Registro" );` ojo, puedes usar `fetchAll` cuando esperas pocos datos. O si no mediante: `while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, "Registro")) {
    $registros[] = new Registro($row);
}`... aquí asumo que tienes una clase llamada `Registro`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que cada vez que iteras en tu while sobreescribes los valores.  Lo que necesitas es un array de objetos asi:

```
public function listarDatos() {
try {
        $sql = "SELECT campo1, campo2, campo3 FROM tabla WHERE campo4 = condicion";
        $bd = new Conn();
        $stmt = $bd->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) { 
            $registros = array();
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $registro = new registrosVista();
                $registro->setCampo1( $row['campo1'] );
                $registro->setCampo2( $row['campo2'] );
                $registro->setCampo3( $row['campo3'] );
                $registros[] = $registro;
            }
        } else { 
            $registros = NULL;
        }
        return $registros;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die ('No se puede ejecutar la consulta');
    }
}
```